# HTTP to HTTPS redirection in Azure APIM

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management, apim

HTTP to HTTPS redirection in Azure APIM. We want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in APIM. I know we can use a policy to redirect, can this be achieved at the API scope.

Comment: Please share the policy which you have tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

*You can refer to this [link](https://dipolimene.medium.com/enforcing-all-requests-to-apim-over-https-2e8f4b7e03e2) to achieve the same.*

Add the below policy in the following way to redirect HTTP to HTTPS at API scope

[image]

[image]

*Click on Inbound Processing to add the policy*

```
<policies>
<inbound>
<choose>
<when  condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Scheme == "http")">
<return-response>
<set-status  code="302"  reason="Requires SSL"  />
<set-header  exists-action="override"  name="Location">
<value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Replace("http://","https://"))</value>
</set-header>
</return-response>
</when>
</choose>
<base  />
</inbound>
<backend>
<base  />
</backend>
<outbound>
<base  />
</outbound>
<on-error>
<base  />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: This is not working at API Scope for me, is it working for you? below is error when I do a Get from postman for one of my endpoints. using http://                                            
 <html>

<head>
 <title>504 Gateway Timeout</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
 <p>Server error - server 40.87.*.* is unreachable at this
  moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></p>
  <!--Zscaler/6.2-->
</body>

</html>

Comment: Yes, its working for me. how are you testing it?

Comment: are you using a custom domain? Refer https://dipolimene.medium.com/enforcing-all-requests-to-apim-over-https-2e8f4b7e03e2, you have multiple options to achieve it. You can use `<choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Scheme == "http")">
            <set-backend-service base-url="your base URL" />
        </when>
    </choose>`

Comment: I am getting 404.\, Ihave the correct backend service bas eurl: 404Resource Not Found

Comment: @ALOK Updated my answer, please check and make the changes accordingly in API settings and in policy

Comment: Yes we have a custom domain and the backend-service base-url is updated . https://dipolimene.medium.com/enforcing-all-requests-to-apim-over-https-2e8f4b7e03e2 I am aware of this link and was following same before reaching out here ":) May be I am missing something

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer? Please change the URL scheme to HTTP(s) and add the modified policy from my answer, it will work

Comment: Error: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:" I get this error when I choose URL scheme as HTTP(s)

Comment: can you share the screenshot of how you are doing this?

Comment: This solution is only working with GET methods.  Can someone please help me with POST or any other method?
For other methods currently it is ignoring method and trying GET method only. So, if you have only POST API on that path, it is throwing 'not found' response.